# combinatorics - $n$ students and $t$ seats

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am working on a problem as follows.

> There are $n$ students and $t$ seats on a table. How many different ways can the students be seated if a), the seats are in a row b), the table is round. Assume that $t>n$.

My claim is that for a), the answer is simply $$\binom{t}{n}n!$$
because there are $\binom{t}{n}$ ways to choose which seats they are going to sit in and the order of $n$ different students is just $n!$.

For the round table, though. I understand the idea that if there are $t=n$ seats, the number of order would be $(n-1)!$ because of the idea where a loop with the same permutation counts as one arrangement.

However I am having trouble when $t>n$. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is to what extent one distinguishes the arrangements. As you explained in the end, ``because of ... loop with the same permutation ...'', we can simply answer Problem b) by dividing ${t\choose n}n!$ by $t$.

Comment: That was simple. Thanks !